# trying to understand some js codes from website

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
    var _b = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0], _bH = "http://mysite.org/";
    if (_b && _b.href != _bH) _b.href = _bH;
</script>
```

Question:
Above code is the html output from one site, what does this mean? googled online, but did not find answer.

Comment: It is representing the base link for that website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`<base href=...>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/base) element is used to specify the base URL against which all relative URLs (modulo @imported CSS) are resolved.  So normally in `<a href="foo.html">` the "foo.html" is interpreted as a file in the same directory as the current page, but a `<base href="http://othersite.com/otherpath/bar">` tag could cause it to behave equivalently to `<a href="http://othersite.com/otherpath/foo.html">`

This script sets that base URL if there is a `<base>` tag, but has no effect otherwise.

This might be part of a misguided attempt to cause relative links to go to the `http` version of the site even when the containing page is served via `https`.

Answer (score 1):

It finds the first `<base>` element on the page and sets its href property to `"http://mysite.org/"`.